# python3 - I do not understand a error message

Tags: python, sonarqube

here is the code I try to use :
NB 'what is here named sonarqube is an application'

```
import os
from distutils.util import strtobool
from sonarqube import SonarQubeClient
from sonarqube.exceptions import ClientError

SONAR_API = SonarQubeClient(token='37ad61922eadXXXXXXXXXXXXXX24649bde442',sonarqube_url=os.getenv('SONARQUBE_API_URL', input('Enter SonarQube API url: ')))

def get_projects_where_develop_is_not_the_default_branch():
    global SONAR_API
    print ('----------------')
    print(SONAR_API.projects)
    print ('----------------')
    p = []
    for project in SONAR_API.projects:
        for branch in SONAR_API.project_branches.get_project_branches_list(project['key']):
            if branch['name'] == 'master' and branch['isMain'] == True:
                print(f"{project['name']} have master branch has default")
                p.append(project['key'])
    return p

#[….]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    projects = get_projects_where_develop_is_not_the_default_branch()
    for project_key in projects:
#[…]
```

so I use python3 to run that & get the error :

```
Enter SonarQube API url: https://sonarqube.XXXXXX.XXXXX/web_api/api/projects
----------------                                                                                                                      
<sonarqube.community.projects.SonarQubeProjects object at 0x7fd57d458c70>                                                                                                                     ----------------    
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                       
File "sonarqube_branches.py", line 34, in <module>                                                                                                                                            projects = get_projects_where_develop_is_not_the_default_branch()
File "sonarqube_branches.py", line 14, in get_projects_where_develop_is_not_the_default_branch                                                                                    
for project in SONAR_API.projects: 
TypeError: 'SonarQubeProjects' object is not iterable                                                                                                              
francois@TLS-2120:~$
```

I don't understand why neither how to fix it
can you help me ?

at this point I get :

````
    print(SONAR_API.projects)
    print ('----------------')```
````

that :

```
<sonarqube.community.projects.SonarQubeProjects at 0x7f97b1XXXXX>
```

I am not sure it can be a clue or just a memory address

Comment: The error points to your `for project in SONAR_API.projects` line and is telling you that `SONAR_API.projects` is not something you can iterate over using `for .. in`. Perhaps it has a function you can call to get an iterator?

Comment: Maybe you need to refresh your `token` after publishing it on public forum

Answer (score 0):

```
projects = list(SONAR_API.projects.search_projects())
```

was solution to get projects list in variable projects.